# unable to bind click event for all columns headers. works only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am looking for help why this code is not working for all headings of column. This code works for fist time for any column but does not fire click event second time. why `$(ColTh).click(function ()` is not being attached to all `th` in header ?

```
$("table.ui-datepicker-calendar > thead").find("th[scope='col']").each(function() {
  var ColTh = $(this);

  $(ColTh).click(function() {
    var colIndex = $(ColTh).index();
    var dateList = [];
    $(ColTh).closest('table').find('tr').each(function() {
      var dateTd = $(this).find('td:eq(' + colIndex + ')');
      var month = $(dateTd).attr('data-month'); //.trigger('click');
      var year = $(dateTd).attr('data-year');
      var day = $(dateTd).children(0).text();
      if (typeof month != 'undefined') {
        var monthINT = parseInt(month.trim());
        monthINT = monthINT + 1;
        var newDate = monthINT + '-' + day.trim() + '-' + year.trim();
        dateList.push(newDate);
      }

    });
    $('#itemSchedulerCal').multiDatesPicker('addDates', dateList);
    dateList = [];

  });

});
```

Comment: I guess it's because the datepicker function redraws again all elements and therefore since are new elements hasn't binded the event anymore. You need to use delegation for the function and there is no need to loop with each ...

Comment: Why not just use delegation? `$("table.ui-datepicker-calendar > thead").on('click', "th[scope='col']",function() { var ColTh = this, colIndex = $(ColTh).index();.... })`

Comment: how i can use delegation here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did following steps to achieve above

Step 1:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function (inst) {
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original(inst);
    var afterShow = this._get(inst, 'afterShow');
    if (afterShow) {
        // trigger custom callback
        afterShow.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null));  
    }
}
```

});

step 2:

```
   $('#itemSchedulerCal').multiDatesPicker({
        showWeek: true,
        minDate: 0,
       dateFormat: "m-d-yy",
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    defaultDate: defdate,
    afterShow: function (inst)
    {
        BindClicks();
    }
});
```

Step 3:

```
function BindClicks() {
// paste all above code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the rest of your code, but about your binding, you can do like this:

```
$("table.ui-datepicker-calendar").on("click", "th[scope='col']", function() {
  var ColTh = $(this);

  var colIndex = ColTh.index();
  var dateList = [];
  ColTh.closest('table').find('tr').each(function() {
    var dateTd = $(this).find('td:eq(' + colIndex + ')');
    var month = dateTd.attr('data-month'); //.trigger('click');
    var year = dateTd.attr('data-year');
    var day = dateTd.children(0).text();
    if (typeof month != 'undefined') {
      var monthINT = parseInt(month.trim());
      monthINT = monthINT + 1;
      var newDate = monthINT + '-' + day.trim() + '-' + year.trim();
      dateList.push(newDate);
    }

  });
  $('#itemSchedulerCal').multiDatesPicker('addDates', dateList);
  dateList = [];
});
```

You are using to `ColTh` as `$(ColTh)`, but `ColTh` is already a jQuery object since you are setting it with `$(this)`. The same applies to `dateTd`.